# Problem with the robot model moving itself

Tags: control

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm a beginner in the ROS/Gazebo/robotics world. I started to work in a robotics research lab in my university, and I have to model an Hexapod.
Apparently, the URDF Xacro is alright: the visuals, collisions, inertia tensors, COM, mass, joint tags, etc..

But when I spawn the model on GazeboSim, it doesn't get immovable. Instead, it get agitated. I thought is was caused by a bad inertia tensor, so I fixed the meshes from the original solid parts, calculated the mass properties and replaced the faulty inertial tags and meshes. But this didn't solve the problem.
When I was recording the screen to post this question, I have noticed that the most I increased the effort limit, the most it became agitated. Here's [the video](https://youtu.be/MNpiOk-2GBU) that shows this behavior. And you can see, in the *rostopic* terminal, that the effort value applied to the joint is the max value (positive or negative) defined in the robot URDF Xacro file, and I don't know why this is happening.

Here's [the robot description](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/emersonfs/z9XMo).

What can be made to solve this problem? I'm getting crazy with this problem haha

Thanks :D

P.S.: Sorry for my English.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/9156/problem-with-the-robot-model-moving-itself/) by [longforgotten](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1313/longforgotten/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 46 on 2015-08-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I made the same question in ROS Answers, and [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/216092/problem-with-the-robot-model-having-spasms/?answer=216098#post-id-216098) helped me a lot.
Like I said in the answer comments, the PID controllers wasn't properly tuned, so I dropped down the PID values and now [the Hexapod is stable](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AE52jGV5QCk).

---

Originally posted by [longforgotten](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1313/longforgotten/) with karma: 46 on 2015-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0